# How to convert JSON value to escaped String in groovy [JsonSlurper]?

Tags: json, groovy, jsonslurper

i have a groovy script that runs on Jenkins, i have build there a json object using JsonSlurper

The json object is a nested one, i would need to convert the nested json child into escaped string value instead of a json object (that's the requirement :) ).

```
{"key1":
    {"key2":
       {"key3":true}
    }
 }
```

Into string escaped value:

```
{"key1": "  {\"key2\":{\"key3\":true}}  " }
```

I'm building the json object by using:

```
def jsont = new JsonSlurper().parseText(row)
```

doing some manipulation to the json, then need to convert to string:

`jsont.key1 =  func(jsont.key1) ----> here i want to convert key1 value to escaped` string

Any suggestion?

Comment: func you are looking for is JsonOutput.toJson(...)

Comment: @daggett JsonOutput.toJson is not escaping the value into an escaped string, any idea on how to convert the json value object into string representation?

Comment: it is converting the object into json string. then if you convert the wrapper object into json - you get an expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import groovy.json.*

def json = '''{"key1":
    {"key2":
       {"key3":true}
    }
 }
'''

def obj = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
obj.key1 = JsonOutput.toJson(obj.key1)

json = JsonOutput.toJson(obj)
```

result:

```
{"key1":"{\"key2\":{\"key3\":true}}"}
```